# How to correctly wait for dependent Neo4j bulk load tasks in C#

Tags: c#, async-await, neo4j

I need to bulk load two groups of data to Neo4j. The second group builds on the nodes and relationships created by the first group, so the second group cannot be loaded until the first group is fully committed.

My current implementation reads like the following.

```cs
public override void Import()
{
    using var session = _driver.AsyncSession(
        x => x.WithDefaultAccessMode(AccessMode.Write));

    var groupA = session.WriteTransactionAsync(async x =>
    {
        var result = await x.RunAsync(queryA);
        return result.ToListAsync();
    });
    groupA.Result.Wait();

    var groupB = session.WriteTransactionAsync(async x =>
    {
        var result = await x.RunAsync(queryB);
        return result.ToListAsync();
    });
    groupB.Result.Wait();
}
```

Note that I cannot change the method to be `async`; hence I am not using `await`.

This method sometimes runs correctly, but sometimes I get an error that reads like the following.

> Cannot access records on this result any more as the result has already been consumed or the query runner where the result is created has already been closed.

I can switch to using the following instead:

```cs
groupA.Wait();
```

Though the issue with this is that the `Status` of `groupA` can be `RanToCompletion` while the `Status` of the `Result` is `Faulted` (e.g., when there is a syntax error with the query). Hence, any possible errors during the execution of `queryA` are not captured, and I guess that requires checking `groupA.Result.Exceptions`.

Given these challenges, I am not sure what is the recommended way of waiting for dependent Neo4j tasks in a synchronous method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to await the `result.ToListAsync` in the scope of the Func. Your transaction is completing before you read the results, and after the transaction is closed you can no longer access the results.

```
    var groupA = session.WriteTransactionAsync(async x =>
    {
        var result = await x.RunAsync(queryA);
        return await result.ToListAsync();
    });
    groupA.Wait();
    var groupB = session.WriteTransactionAsync(async x =>
    {
        var result = await x.RunAsync(queryB);
        return await result.ToListAsync();
    });
    groupB.Wait();
```

The reason it sometimes completes successfully is because the `result.ToListAsync` task completes before your transaction has been commited & closed.